# Additional end anchor tags added after using link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason rails is generating additional anchor tags after  I use link_to inside an HTML anchor tag. Is this HTML design or rails constrain.?

```
<li>
                <a id="user-menu" href="#">
                    <%=current_user.first_name%>
                    <div id="bubblemenu" class="lotusBubble-content" style="display:none"> 
                      <ul>
                          <li><%= link_to "My Profile", current_user %></li>
                          <li>My Bookmarks</li>
                          <li>My Active</li>
                          <li>My Expired</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
```

This generates a HTML like this

```
            <li>
                <a id="user-menu" href="#">Srikanth</a>
                  <div id="bubblemenu" class="lotusBubble-content" style="display:none">
                              <a id="user-menu" href="#"> </a>
                              <ul>
                                    <a id="user-menu" href="#">
                                    </a>
                                    <li><a id="user-menu" href="#"></a><a href="/user.1">My Profile</a></li>
                                    <li>My Bookmarks</li>
                                    <li>My Active</li>
                                    <li>My Expired</li>
                              </ul>
```

why is there so anchor tags added automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this restriction. Anchor inside an anchor is not permitted as per HTML standards. If at all something like that occurs, then the browsers atomically ends the outer anchor

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Comment: Where do you see an anchor within an anchor?

Comment: <a id="user-menu" href="#">
    <%=current_user.first_name%> link_to generates an another anchor. This leads to a nested anchor scenario

Answer (score 0):

It is due to you are using the instruction link_to, this function creates the an anchor ta automatically when it is executed